# C# capture internet audio stream

Tags: c#, audio, streaming

Is there a way to capture an audiostream from the internet using C#?

Comment: More information needed. What type of audio stream? What website? Is it legal to record the stream in the first place?

Comment: In the absence of any more detail, "Yes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several. Among them:

1. http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html
2. http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can get it working